# Parental Control Time Limits not taking effect

Tags: macos, parental-controls

My step-daughter has an iMac with OS X Lion.  She has an account that auto logs in, with no password on it.  Previously, we'd been using the parental controls to keep her from getting up and using the computer in the middle of the night.  It was set to limit computer use from 8:30 PM to 8:00 AM.  That seemed to work.

My daughter is grounded from computer and video games today.  I tried setting the time limits to 8:01 AM to 8:00 AM, but she promptly strolled in and started checking her email and surfing the web.  I tried setting it to kick in a couple minutes in the future (10:45 AM to 8:00 AM) and it didn't block the account when 10:45 came around.  I tried removing parental controls completely and then adding them back, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

What am I missing?  Her account is set as "managed".  The clock has the correct time, but, nothing seems to be enforced.

Comment: If you really don't want her going on for a while, set a password for her account. Like `tr8e7Waag0pp8locvx11aqfergd847563625`.

Comment: I considered doing that.  It seemed less friendly than the "you're not allowed on right now, if you really want to use the computer get an admin to give you time" message, so I wanted to avoid it.

Comment: Magically, the next day the limits I set kicked in.  I still have no idea why they wouldn't go that first day.  I'm a little disappointed, but past the initial crisis.

Comment: Well, that is good then. Good luck with future Parental Controls endeavours!

Comment: wonder if she has to logout then login first for them to take affect?